# What GUI libraries does the spotify windows application use? Nice metallic borderless look?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, spotify, borderless

I think spotify in windows looks very nice, clearly not native windows gui.

Seems to be completely borderless with a metallic look.

I was wondering what libraries did they use to create such a nice looking app?

Is it possible to create a nice looking app cross platform (well mac and windows really)?

Answer (score 2):

The UI is completely written in-house although some of the components are from the system (Input text fields, Menubar, etc). For Linux these components comes from QT4. QT4 is only used on the Linux builds.

Comment: For linux you see the used QT-Elements via
`$ strings /usr/bin/spotify | more`
e.g. QMenu, QTextLayout, QPainter and so on

Answer (score 1):

Spotify uses QT4 for it's UI to create a cross platform Unified look.